# ¿Cómo enlazar una tabla de excel a mySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-workbench

Estoy tratando de hacer una base de datos con mySQL, he seguido varios tutoriales sin éxito alguno, según leí se pueden importar archivos .csv en mySQL pero, al momento de importarlo me da un mensaje de error:

```
> 12:49:32 Restoring
> C:\Users\bms\Documents\20171009_CLIENTES_Prospectos.csv Running:
> mysql.exe
> --defaults-file="c:\users\bms\appdata\local\temp\tmp2v2ott.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments  < "C:\\Users\\bms\\Documents\\20171009_CLIENTES_Prospectos.csv" ERROR
> 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
> the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '3Tek Solar, si ,si ,No , "Av. Industrial #13286
> Tijuana BC. CP 22105",+52 664 60' at line 1
> 
> Operation failed with exitcode 1 12:49:32 Import of
> C:\Users\bms\Documents\20171009_CLIENTES_Prospectos.csv has finished
> with 1 errors
```

La parte inicial de mi base de datos es la siguiente:

```
CREATE DATABASE pvm;


DROP TABLE clientes_prospecto;
CREATE TABLE pvm. clientes_prospecto
(
Empresa_ID int,
Nombre_Empresa varchar(30),
Sistema_red boolean,
Sistema_aislado boolean,
Instalcion_menor boolean,
Instalacion_mayor boolean,
Direccion varchar (100),
telefono varchar (15),
pagina_web varchar (30),
correo varchar (30)
);
select * from clientes_prospecto
```

Mi archivo de Excel hasta donde tengo entendido esta bien, las cifras que hay están separadas por puntos y no por comas para evitar problemas al pasar los daros, pero sigue sin funcionar, estoy utilizando MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.3.9 CE build 10690321 (64 bit), Gracias.

Comment: En el CSV busca ese valor que se indica falla; tu tabla considera 10 valores a ingresar, la que se muestra falla al parecer solo incluye 6, faltan valores o agrega "," (comas) para "completarlo" (si se permite vacio/nulo); da un viztazo a alguna linea anterior que si se inserta y compara tanto cantidad de datos, formato y comas existentes que sí permiten su importación. Suerte.

Comment: Oh ya, y también en mi tabla tengo booloeanos y no en mi archivo a exportar haha, gracias.